# Storing value used in POST form in a PHP variable

Tags: php, html

I'm using a POST form that transfers data from one PHP file to another.. no issues there. However, I'm trying to store session data into a PHP variable.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
{
    session_start();

    echo "<form action='../account.php' method='post'>";
        echo "<p><b>Username: </b><input id='uname' type='username' name='uname' align='middle'></p>";
        echo "<p><b>Password: </b><input id='pword' type='password' name='pword' align='middle'></p>";
        echo "<p><input type='Submit' style='width:15%'></p>";
    echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

I need the "uname" value to be stored as $_SESSION['login_user'] upon clicking submit, but this shouldn't prevent POSTing to the next page. How can I handle this?

Comment: just use `account.php` to set the session variable. the form is going to be processed there anyways\. of course don't forget to start the session there also

Comment: I thought about that.. but I felt it would be cleaner if done in this file. Either way, if I take that approach, should I execute session_start() there as well or in this file?

Comment: yes, of course you should start the session there also. you need to. you can't process the input in that same file since you explicitly set the `action=""` to `account.php` in which the post values will be there, unless you change your mind and process the post values in the same file. then you could process the setting of session in there also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session_start() should be initialized before anything you do in php

in your account.php initialize the session :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $_POST['uname'];
//rest of the stuff
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In account.php, do following assignment:

```
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $_POST['uname'];
```